# Handling errors for "Small" function in excel, when the length of array is less than the array provided

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to consider only the **least few in an array of some X number's**, i am getting **#NUM!** error when the function cannot find the length specified.

Example- Small(range,{1,2,3})
here the range of cells that contain numeric value is "range" and {1,2,3} is the 3 smallest number to be considered, what happens if the range has only 2 digits instead of 10.

Any advises will be helpful.
 I was expecting a solution where the number can be made adjusted from the numerics available.

Here is the best example i can give

[image: Please refer this image for exactly what i am doing]

[image: For Ron Rosenfeld reference]

Comment: `IFERROR(SMALL(…),""`?

Comment: IFEERROR will make the result as "0",

Comment: No, it does not. `IFERROR(SMALL(your_formula,{1,2,3}),""` will return `""` in the 3rd and/or 2nd spots if you have less than three values. And that would be ignored by `SUM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IFERROR`

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SMALL(A7:E7,{1,2,3}),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, Ron Rosenfeld thanks for the answer, but still i cant get this working, please look at this image added with my question. the sum of small 2 number should be -2 right ?

Comment: Yes, and using the formula you show in the adjacent column, that is the answer I get. However, it may be that in your version of Excel, you need to confirm this **array** formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of array entering the formula over three cells, put this in the first cell and copy down three:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(range,ROW(ZZ1),"")
```

Now it will not show the `#NUM` error if there are less than 3 items in the `range`

Comment: Hello @Scott Craner, thanks for your answer, can you please let me know what ROW(ZZ1) does ?

Comment: @Directionsky it is a simple counter that as it is drug/copied down increases by 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SMALL(range,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MIN(COUNT(range),3))))
```